# How to take out first 2 digit number from a string in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 strings:

```
"SP-1-15::PROVPEC=NTK555EA,CTYPE=\"SP-2\",PEC=NTK555EA,REL= 1  ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=00-005-20-03,ONSC=00-005-19-50:IS-ANR,FLT"
"SP-1-16::PROVPEC=NTK555FA,CTYPE=\"SP-2 Dual CPU\",PEC=NTK555FA,REL= 1  ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=UNKNOWN,ONSC=UNKNOWN:IS-ANR,FLT"
```

I want 2 things:

1. If `WRK` in string remove `15` and `16` from `(SP-1-15 and SP-1-16)` resp.
2. If `WRK` is not in string, remove the odd value which in this case is `15`.

Comment: Could you make your question clearer by making it a little less specific to your particular problem? For example, maybe get rid of the "finding 'WRK'" part. Also, did you even look for the String `find()` method before asking?

Comment: Yes.i did used that but it didnt work out for me. Basically first thing first is i want to take out only those lines from a multiline output whihc has text 'SP' in it.Then on those lines i want to find out if any of them (it would be either 1 or 2 lines atmost) contains WRK then take out the number whihc is there after SP-1-<d> it it doesnt then take out the odd number , in case i ave only 1 string having SP in it, i will fetch the number whihc is there in SP-1-<d>

Comment: after you remove 15 do you want the text to read `SP-1-` or `SP-1`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `re.search` and `re.sub` to meet the conditions of finding `WRK` in both I used `.join()` to find it

```
s = ["SP-1-15::PROVPEC=NTK555EA,CTYPE=\"SP-2\",PEC=NTK555EA,REL= 1  ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=00-005-20-03,ONSC=00-005-19-50:IS-ANR,FLT", "SP-1-16::PROVPEC=NTK555FA,CTYPE=\"SP-2 Dual CPU\",PEC=NTK555FA,REL= 1  ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=UNKNOWN,ONSC=UNKNOWN:IS-ANR,FLT"
]

import re

j = ''.join(s)

find_sp = re.compile(r'\d+::', re.I)

for idx, item in enumerate(s):
    if 'WRK' in j:
        s[idx] = re.sub(r'\d+::', '::', item)
    elif 'WRK' not in j:
        num = find_sp.search(item)
        x = num.group(0).strip('::')
        if int(x) % 2:
            s[idx] = re.sub(r'\d+::', '::', item)
        else:
            pass
print(s)
```

> ```
> ['SP-1-::PROVPEC=NTK555EA,CTYPE="SP-2",PEC=NTK555EA,REL= 1  
> ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=00-005-20-03,ONSC=00-005-19-50:IS-
> ANR,FLT', 'SP-1-16::PROVPEC=NTK555FA,CTYPE="SP-2 Dual   
> CPU",PEC=NTK555FA,REL= 1  
> ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=UNKNOWN,ONSC=UNKNOWN:IS-ANR,FLT']
> ```

and here with `WRK` in one of the lines

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 strings.py
> ['SP-1-::PROVPEC=WRKNTK555EA,CTYPE="SP-2",PEC=NTK555EA,REL= 1   
> ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=00-005-20-03,ONSC=00-005-19-50:IS-
> ANR,FLT', 'SP-1-::PROVPEC=NTK555FA,CTYPE="SP-2 Dual 
> CPU",PEC=NTK555FA,REL= 1
> ,CLEI=,SER=NNTM,MDAT=UNKNOWN,AGE=UNKNOWN,ONSC=UNKNOWN:IS-ANR,FLT']
> ```